# shortcut to see all the properties of widget in flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I m new at flutter, I m using android studio and I want to know is there is any shortcut to see all the property of any particular widget at the time android studio it self, without going to the documentation page.pls help, it really help to reduce the development time.

Comment: Comand-space or option-space on mac

Comment: use ctrl + p and you will see all the parameters also use ctrl + q for quick documentation.

Comment: thanx @delmin option-space get work.

Comment: thanx @hiwajalal , the command+p is also work for the same

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my case it's <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>. But I'm not using apple's mac mini keyboard.

So "In my case" <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> is the most useful. Then you can click on some widget e.g Text and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd> to see documentation. You can also press <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> to see all properties in inline mode.

Answer (score 4):

This feature is called Code Completion:
[image]

On my MacbookPro & Android Studio Smart Code Completion -> <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> was working. However Basic key shortcut <kbd>^</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> was shadowed by MacOs keyboard input settings. So disabling the `select the previous input source` solved this shadowing. Now both shortcuts are working.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Mac it's `(control + J)`, if not working go to preferences or settings, then head to keymap, and then there search for documentation. you will get the shortcut.
Also try `( command + p )`, I think that would work for what you are trying to find.